# Access VM's with in dedicated server using Windows remote desktop

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I have windows 2016 dedicated server hosted on godaddy.com ,and  I have like 3 VM within this dedicated server. so in order to connect to these VM's through public  can you recommend a solution? because if i enter the public ip in my remote it will try to connect to dedicated server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a vpn server, add a vpn client to the vm you wish to connect to, as long as the vm has access to the internet.  That will give you a private subnet and a route to the vm.  OpenVPN is very good at this.  You will need to allow the ports in the Windows Server.

OpenVPN is free, it is an open source product. There are other vpns also, the point is to use a vpn to have an easy way to route to your vms.

Comment: but is it safe? and should I buy this open vpn account or software? and what do you think of portforwarding if i forwarded from dedicated server to vm's inside?

Comment: I edited the post, you do not have to pay anything - vpns are used for security in organizations throughout the world. It is a good option.

Comment: Port forwarding will work too, but VPN is certainly the safest and most secure way to do this. I often run a special dedicated thin virtual machine which hosts a VPN service (and only that), just to not to run it on the host itself.

Comment: People I managed to use this website and actually they are generous that the give vpn for 3 devices for free, https://openvpn.net ?please any one tried mention website ?

Comment: Yes, they have a couple of products that will work for that. Look into openvpn access server and openvpn cloud, both come with free connections.

Comment: @jdopenvpn, I see!  I am using them already